# How to prove that Java doesn't support Multiple Inheritance?

Tags: java, oop

How can we prove that java doesn't support multiple inheritance?

Is there any alternative method to implement Multiple Inheritance in Java?

Comment: Prove? There is a language specification. Multiple inheritance is not in there.

Comment: Try compiling `public class Child extends Parent1, Parent2 {...`

Comment: No proof is required of statements in the JLS. You just cite them.

Comment: [JLS 8.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) describes the structure of super class declaration. Note, that a class can implement several interfaces. For that, see [JLS 8.1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5). (I looked it up in the JLS of Java 8.)

Comment: If you learned a lot of theory in your class, covering how to prove absence or existence of features, you should take a look at the exact definition your prof used for "Multiple Inheritance" (note that allowing multiple interfaces can be interpreted as Multiple Inheritance, according to some definitions), and then try a proof by contradiction and construction (you construct something that uses multiple inheritance in its most general form but contradicts with the specs).

Comment: You should also note that proof by compilation isn't valid, as it doesn't exclude the possibility of compiler bugs, however remote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can we prove that java doesnt support multiple inheritance?

Create 3 classes in the *same* package, let's say `Test1`, `Test2` and `Test3`. And try this. You will get an **error**:

```
public class Test extends Test2, Test3
{
    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

> Is there any alternative method to implement Multiple Inheritance in Java

Yes, you can make your class implement multiple (1 or more) *interfaces*.

Answer (score 4):

There is **no multiple inheritance** in java as it is specified by the language specification.

To prove it simply try to extend 2 unrelated classes:

```
public class MyClass extends Number, AbstractList {

}
```

This will result in a compile error.

You can do one thing however:

Excerpt from [java magic part 4: Unsafe](http://mishadoff.github.io/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/)

> Multiple Inheritance
>
> There is no multiple inheritance in java.
>   Correct, except we can cast every type to every another one, if we want.

```
long intClassAddress = normalize(getUnsafe().getInt(new Integer(0), 4L));
long strClassAddress = normalize(getUnsafe().getInt("", 4L));
getUnsafe().putAddress(intClassAddress + 36, strClassAddress);
```

> This snippet adds `String` class to `Integer` superclasses, so we can cast without runtime exception.

```
(String) (Object) (new Integer(666))
```

I really ***do not recommend*** this. It is considered a "best practice" to implement multiple interfaces if you want something which resembles multiple inheritance or as others pointed out you can use *composition* and *delegation* as well.

Comment: Perhaps an example other than String would be better, because String is final, and so, even if this were possible, it would still fail to compile.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any alternative method to implement Multiple Inheritance in Java

Depending on what you need, you can get almost the same effect with

- implementing multiple interfaces
- using object composition and delegating method calls to the objects that implement the pieces you would otherwise have inherited

Answer (score 2):

Java does not support multiple inheritance but in Java you can achieve multiple inheritance using less complex feature called - **Interfaces**.

Comment: No, you don't. Interface provides only a subset of true multiple inheritance properties. It's wrong and misleading to consider these two terms as interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

If an one class directly inherited from two or more classes it will be multiple inheritances.  But in java this is not allowed.

We don’t need a proof as it is specified in java language specification.

However If you need a proof try to compile below(This will not compile)

```
class A{
 void doSomething(){
   System.out.println(“from class A”);
 }
}


class B{
 void doSomething(){
  System.out.println(“from class B”);
 }
}


class C extends A,B{
  public static void main(String arr[]){
   C cob= new C();
   cob.doSomething();//now how does compiler knows which super method to call?
  }
}
```

The reason that Java's creators chose not to allow multiple inheritance is that it can become quite messy. But indeed you can have something like this.

```
public interface InterfaceA {

  public void doSomething();
}



public interface InterfaceB {

 public void doSomething();
}



 public interface InterfaceC extends InterfaceA, InterfaceB {

  //same method is declared in InterfaceA and InterfaceB both
  public void doSomething();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
  public void methodAClassA()
  {
  System.out.println("In ClassA MethodA");
  }
}
class B extends A{
  public void methodAClassA(){
  System.out.print("in Class B Method ClassA");
  }
}
class C extends A,B {}
```

Which is not possible because
 if you use the above code the compiler does not
 know which instance method could be used in the class C
 So they made it as error it will show the compilation error.

Comment: indentation hurts less.

Comment: The reason advanced, mis-spelt, and hidden inside the code, is not correct. Other languages manage it somehow. -1

Comment: You fixed the form, but not the content.